# Understanding parameters of the STATICCALL opcode in Solidity inline assembly

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly

I am new to inline assembly. I have tried understanding different opcodes, and understood quite a bit, but still not be able to correlate them in context to **STATICCALL** opcode. Kindly help me understand what's happening here in this piece of code

```
function getUint(address addr, bytes memory data) internal view returns (uint result) {
    result = 0;

    assembly {
        let status := staticcall(16000, addr, add(data, 32), mload(data), 0, 0)

        // Success!
        if eq(status, 1) {
            if eq(returndatasize(), 32) {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, 32)
                result := mload(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I have understood from solidity assembly documentation,

**STATICCALL: identical to call(g, a, 0, in, insize, out, outsize) but does not have **v** value and do not allow state modifications**

How do the parameters in the above code represent **in**, **insize**, **out** and **outsize**?

Answer (score 3):

From the call you have

```
staticcall(16000, addr, add(data, 32), mload(data), 0, 0)
```

- **16000** is gas
- **addr** target address
- **add(data, 32)** input
- **mload(data)** input size
- **0** output
- **0** output size

For `bytes` the first 32 bytes are the size and it follow the raw data. `mload(data)` read 32 bytes pointed by data (it returns the length of data). `add(data, 32)` it moves the pointer to the raw data skipping the size field.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understood the input and inputsize now, but can you explain a bit, why the output and output size are 0?

Comment: And data here is actually the function signature as, `abi.encodeWithSignature("myFunction()")`. So, does it mean, `mload(data)` will read 32 bytes pointed by this signature, and `add(data, 32)` will point the raw data for it?

Comment: @RazorSharp Setting output and output size to 0 is due to historical reason. In early EVM versions you had to know the output size in advance, it was a limiting factor for some kind of operations (proxy contracts) so in the [Bizantium fork](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-609) new opcodes were introduced ReturnDataSize and ReturnDataCopy. This allow the caller to determine the output size after the call (ReturnDataSize) and allowing copying to memory (ReturnDataCopy).

Comment: @RazorSharp The `abi.encodeWithSignature(..)` encodes a function call using the [Contracts ABI](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/abi-spec.html). Since `myFunction()` doesn't have any parameters it should return the function identifier which is in hexa "c3780a3a", mload(data) should be 4 and add(data, 32) will point to the function identifiier.